# Can I ask a question about ODBC driver and license?

Tags: support

I want to ask a question about whether a license is required to use an ODBC driver, but I don't know whether it is on topic or not.

The question I'm meant to ask is:

> We have a product that uses SQL Server as the database back-end. We want to switch over to SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver instead of the default SQL Server ODBC driver that comes default with the OS installation.
>
> Is there any additional licensing requirement that I have to be aware of?
>
> Currently, I have no idea what license is used when the product is sold to the customer. However, it is safe to assume that the license covers the usage of the default SQL Server ODBC driver.

Comment: It's on-topic from what I can tell - it'd be good to show whatever research you've done in the question though?

Comment: I don't think relying on peer advice is a good idea for a licensing question - are you willing to bet your job on some stranger's answer? Instead of making "safe" assumptions, why not contact Microsoft directly about this?

Comment: You might also contact your Licensed Authorized Reseller, LAR, as they usually have a specialist versed in leagalese

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/487/1186

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I am more of asking whether anyone has been in the same situation before, and whether a license is necessary. There is zero risk for me, since it has to go through people who deal directly with the legal aspect of the problems. I'm just doing an initial reality check here.

Comment: But someone in that scenario three months ago might have been under a different license agreement than you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Anyway, it seems that this site doesn't welcome such question, so I will not ask it here. Please close this as duplicate of the question you cited.